# PHP Session value is change dramatically

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have 2 php files and session is changing data  weirdly, can not understand php session behavior. help me to understand this situation.

i know this is not right way to code and also my problem is solve if i use id1 or another key name for session (i.e. $_SESSION['id1'] but i just want to know session behavior in php.

**index.php**

```
<body>
        <?php
        session_start();
        if(isset($_SESSION["product"]))
       print_r($_SESSION["product"]);
        ?>

        <a href="product.php?id=1">product 1</a>
           <a href="product.php?id=2">product 2</a>
    </body>
```

**product.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
 if(isset($_SESSION["product"]))
    print_r($_SESSION["product"]);
if(isset($_GET['btnsubmit']))
{
    $id=$_SESSION['id'];
    $array=array();
    if(isset($_SESSION["product"]))
    {
        $array=$_SESSION["product"];
    }
    $onearay=array();
    $onearay["pname"]=$_SESSION["id"];
    $onearay["qty"]=1;

    $array[]=$onearay;
   $_SESSION["product"]=$array;
   header("location:index.php");
}
?>
<form>
    <input type="submit" name="btnsubmit" value="submit"/>
</form>
<?php

$_SESSION["id"]=$_GET["id"];
echo "<br/>";
 if(isset($_SESSION["product"]))
  print_r($_SESSION["product"]);
?>
```

**output when product 2 is in my session and i am opening page with product.php?id=1**

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [pname] => 2 [qty] => 1 ) )
```

*submit button here show*

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [pname] => 1 [qty] => 1 ) )
```

Comment: Likely this line on your product.php page: `$_SESSION["id"]=$_GET["id"];` you over write the output from the code above by re-assigning the `get` value.

Comment: but i already create new array and add $_SESSION['id'] in that array

Answer (score 0):

It would help you to have a series of functions (or a class) that do the cart work independent of your site code. It would help organize your code better I think.

```
<?php

// ===== NEEDS TO GO AT TOP OF PAGE FROM HERE =====//

function ShoppingCart()
    {
        // If action add to cart
        if(isset($_REQUEST['add']))
            AddToCart();
        // Add more actions / functions
    }

function AddToCart()
    {
        // If a product id is set add quantity
        if(isset($_REQUEST['id']) && is_numeric($_REQUEST['id'])) {
                // Set the default qty value
                $qty = (isset($_REQUEST['qty']) && is_numeric($_REQUEST['qty']))? $_REQUEST['qty']:1;

                $_SESSION['cart'][$_REQUEST['id']]['qty'] = (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$_REQUEST['id']]))? ($qty+$_SESSION['cart'][$_REQUEST['id']]['qty']): $qty;
            }
    }

session_start();
// Create cart session instance
ShoppingCart();
// ===== NEEDS TO GO AT TOP OF PAGE TO HERE =====//

print_r($_SESSION); ?>

<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="123"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="qty" value="1"/>
    <input type="submit" name="add" value="ADD TO CART"/>
</form>
```

**GIVES YOU**

```
Array
(
    [cart] => Array
        (
            [123] => Array
                (
                    [qty] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: i know all that things i just want to know why that happening